# PHP Array problems....if anyone can assist!

Tags: php

Thanks for the contributions so far - I can see now that $rowq is not a single array but lots of them - I'd like to bring all the rows back in the array, any suggestions?

First off, the code which brings back my data into an array:

```
function fetch_questions($page) {
global $link;
$proc = mysqli_prepare($link, "SELECT * FROM tques WHERE page = ?");
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($proc, "i", $page);
mysqli_stmt_execute($proc);


$rowq = array();
stmt_bind_assoc($proc, $rowq);

// loop through all result rows
while ($proc->fetch()) {
//      print_r($rowq);
}


mysqli_stmt_close($proc);
mysqli_clean_connection($link);
return($rowq);
}
```

Now, when I `print_r($rowq);'  I get the following, which is all good:

`Array ( [questions] => q1 [qnum] => 1 [qtext] => I find my job meaningful [page] => 1 ) Array ( [questions] => q2 [qnum] => 2 [qtext] => I find my job interesting [page] => 1 ) Array ( [questions] => q3 [qnum] => 3 [qtext] => My work supports ABC's objective [page] => 1 ) Array ( [questions] => q4 [qnum] => 4 [qtext] => I am able to balance my work and home life [page] => 1 ) Array ( [questions] => q5 [qnum] => 5 [qtext] => I am clear about what is expected of me in my job [page] => 1 ) Array ( [questions] => q6 [qnum] => 6 [qtext] => My induction helped me to settle into my job [page] => 1 ) Array ( [questions] => q7 [qnum] => 7 [qtext] => I understand the ABC vision [page] => 1 ) Array ( [questions] => q8 [qnum] => 8 [qtext] => I know how what I do fits into my team's objectives [page] => 1 )`

Now, in my php page I have the following piece of script:

`$questions = fetch_questions($page);`

And when I print_r $questions, as below:

`print_r($questions);`

I only get the following back from the array, 1 row:

`Array ( [questions] => q8 [qnum] => 8 [qtext] => I know how what I do fits into my team's objectives [page] => 1 )`

Any ideas why that might be?

Thanks in advance,

Homer.

Comment: If $page is controlled by the user then this is a sql injection vulnerability.  Make sure to sanitize $page=intval($page);

Comment: @Rook, thanks - it's been pointed out that I was using this incorrectly - $page isn't user controlled but have now changed it to what it should be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `$rowq` variable is only holding the last row that was fetched. When you `print_r` during your fetch loop, each row is fetched into the `$rowq` variable, and then immediately printed, but because you overwrite the variable each iteration, when the loop completes only the final row is contained within `$rowq`.

If you want to hang onto all the rows, you can augment your function:

```
function fetch_questions($page) {
  // ...

  $rows = array();
  while ($proc->fetch()) {
    $rows[] = $rowq;
  }

  // ...

  return $rows;
}
```

With this code (only the relevant parts are included), every time a row is fetched, it is placed within an array `$rows`, which then contains **all** rows when the loop completes.

Comment: @Daniel - thanks - I do want to keep ALL the rows - I've tried adding your code to augment mine but no joy - any suggestions?

Comment: @Daniel - ignore last post - have no sorted that. :-)
thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You're not collecting the results in an array. You were `print_r`-ing each individual row in the `while` loop.

So if you look carefully at the results you show, this is what actually happened:

```
// in each iteration of the while loop
// print_r( $rowq )
Array ( [questions] => q1 [qnum] => 1 [qtext] => I find my job meaningful [page] => 1 )
// print_r( $rowq )
Array ( [questions] => q2 [qnum] => 2 [qtext] => I find my job interesting [page] => 1 ) 
// print_r( $rowq )
Array ( [questions] => q3 [qnum] => 3 [qtext] => My work supports ABC's objective [page] => 1 )
// etc..
```

It just presented itself behind each other.

So effectively you are only returning the last row from the while loop when calling the function.

As a side note:
You are not using `mysqli_prepare` as intended. You should replace `$page` with a ? placeholder, like so:

```
$proc = mysqli_prepare($link, "SELECT * FROM tques WHERE page = ?");
// the following statement will properly replace the placeholder with $page
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($proc, "i", $page);
```

Comment: Thanks for the heads up on the mysqli_prepare - modified that and I can now see that the Array is fresh each time and that I am overwriting $rowq.  Any suggestions on how I keep ALL the rows in the array?